# Insert Publishing HTML column value into MS word document

Tags: html, ms-word, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary

How can I insert content/value of Publishing HTML column of document library SharePoint 2013 into MS word document?

Quick parts in MS Word don't display that column so I don't know how to import it.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to insert such a field manually, via OpenXML, by editing xml-files inside the word-file. But unfortunately Quick parts don't support formatting.